# UICollectionVIewの１つのCellを削除して更新する方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

現在、UICollectionViewを使って各自の日記を閲覧するタイムラインの機能を実装しております。
そこで、その日記の削除処理をした時にCollectionViewを更新したいです。

該当のcellのみを削除したいです。

しかし、初回に表示したcellの内容から変化させることができません。

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

では描画できないのでしょうか？

勉強不足で恐縮です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Collection View プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf) （PDF書類）これの21ページに説明が載っています。